# How to save response in my variable from webservice

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, webservice-client

I am new to web services, I have trial version of flight state, how to get response in C#?

I have below web service

```
https://api.flightstats.com/flex/airlines/soap/v1/airlinesService?wsdl
https://api.flightstats.com/flex/schedules/soap/v1/scheduledFlightsService?wsdl
```

I want call its methods and response save in my variable but its shows error ;( I have added this service through Service Reference and call its methods.

This is my code - please help

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServiceReference2.flightServiceClient obje = new Windowsflightstate.ServiceReference2.flightServiceClient();

    // How to get response 
    string[] resultdata = obje.flightStatus_arr("b2113423", "65fa387418310aec95a688737f8e0b13", "", "EK4158", 2016, 03, 07, "", "", "", "");

    flightscheduleswebservice.scheduledFlightServiceClient client = new Windowsflightstate.flightscheduleswebservice.scheduledFlightServiceClient();
    client.byFlight_Arriving("b2113423", "65fa387418310aec95a688737f8e0b13",null, "EK4158", 2016, 03, 07, null, null);

    // it is showing error how to get response
    string[] resultdata2 =  client.byFlight_Arriving("b2113423", "65fa387418310aec95a688737f8e0b13", null, "EK4158", 2016, 03, 07, null, null);
}
```

Please see this image:

[image]

Comment: From the error message, **obviously** the web service calls returns an object of type `responseByFlight`, but you're trying to store it as `string[] resultdata ` .....  If the web service call returns a `responseByFlight` - you need to store the response into a variable of type `responseByFlight` ....

Comment: It says right in the error message: `obje.flightStatus_arr` and `client.byFlight_Arriving` don't return something of type `string[]` so your shouldn't declare `resultdata` and `resultdata2` as type `string[]`.

Comment: how to do this ;( please help

Comment: Just simply `Windowsflightstate.flightscheduleswebservice.responseByFlight resultdata = obje.flightStatus_arr(....)`.....  after all, `responseByFlight` is just a **class** (datatype) in C# - you can define a variable to be of any defined data type......

Comment: i cant understand sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this code - assign the **response** from the web service call to the **datatype** (class) that the web service method returns:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServiceReference2.flightServiceClient obje = new Windowsflightstate.ServiceReference2.flightServiceClient();

    // How to get response 
    flightscheduleswebservice.responseByFlight resultdata = obje.flightStatus_arr("b2113423", "65fa387418310aec95a688737f8e0b13", "", "EK4158", 2016, 03, 07, "", "", "", "");

    // show errors if any
    Console.WriteLine("HTTP status code: {0}", resultdata.error.httpStatusCode);
    Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", resultdata.error.errorCode);
    Console.WriteLine("Error message: {0}", resultdata.error.errorMessage);

    // display info, if any
    if (resultdata.scheduledFlights != null && resultdata.scheduledFlights.Length > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number of flights returned: {0}", resultdata.scheduledFlights.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Flight #1 - carrier name: {0}", resultdata.scheduledFlights[0].carrier.name);
        Console.WriteLine("Flight #1 - departure airport name: {0}", resultdata.scheduledFlights[0].departureAirport.name);
        Console.WriteLine("Flight #1 - arrival airport name: {0}", resultdata.scheduledFlights[0].arrivalAirport.name);
    }
}
```

From the error it is **obvious** that the web service calls returns an instance of a class called **`flightscheduleswebservice.responseByFlight`** - not an array of strings that you were trying to assign it to.

The whole point of using web services using the built-in mechanisms in C# is that you get back a nice **response object** - not just a pile of XML strings. You don't need to parse the XML response yourself - that `ServiceReference2.flightServiceClient` class handles of all this for you - you get back a nice, normal .NET **object** that you can work with!

Comment: Many Thanks for your Respones but Sir, i think you don't understand my question, i want save these data like date time store in my variable string or arraylist, how do this, i am asking this..., @Marc_s

Comment: @AddiKhan: you're getting back an **object** - not a single string - you can store the **entire object** as shown in my response, and you can look at all the details that are returned in that object and store those separately, if you like......

Comment: ;( how ;( i don't understand ;(

Comment: i am very thankful to you If you like answer my question please copy and paste code in VS and add web service and do something like as i want,  because i an new in web service and use every method who return string or array thats why i can't understand how do this, this type of web service

Comment: Well, **what** from this response do you want to extract and store? Look at the definition of the `responseByFlight` class - this is just **plain C#** code - read it! What are you intereted in? What do you want to extract from this response and store elsewhere?

Comment: i want flight arrival details like date time or airport something like

Comment: @AddiKhan: updated my response - right now, your call will return an error `A required airline code was not present`

Comment: Thanks for your response Sir,